# Creating a spinner for choosing country code

Tags: android, spinner, mobile-country-code

I want to create a spinner for selecting a country and getting its country code.

I already found this item list:

```
<string-array name="countryCodes">
    <item>93,AF</item>
    <item>355,AL</item>
    <item>213,DZ</item>
    <item>376,AD</item>
    <item>244,AO</item>
    <item>672,AQ</item>
    <item>54,AR</item>
    <item>374,AM</item>
    <item>297,AW</item>
    <item>61,AU</item>
    <item>43,AT</item>
    <item>994,AZ</item>
    <item>973,BH</item>
    <item>880,BD</item>
    <item>375,BY</item>
    <item>32,BE</item>
    <item>501,BZ</item>
    <item>229,BJ</item>
    <item>975,BT</item>
    <item>591,BO</item>
    <item>387,BA</item>
    <item>267,BW</item>
    <item>55,BR</item>
    <item>673,BN</item>
    <item>359,BG</item>
    <item>226,BF</item>
    <item>95,MM</item>
    <item>257,BI</item>
    <item>855,KH</item>
    <item>237,CM</item>
    <item>1,CA</item>
    <item>238,CV</item>
    <item>236,CF</item>
    <item>235,TD</item>
    <item>56,CL</item>
    <item>86,CN</item>
    <item>61,CX</item>
    <item>61,CC</item>
    <item>57,CO</item>
    <item>269,KM</item>
    <item>242,CG</item>
    <item>243,CD</item>
    <item>682,CK</item>
    <item>506,CR</item>
    <item>385,HR</item>
    <item>53,CU</item>
    <item>357,CY</item>
    <item>420,CZ</item>
    <item>45,DK</item>
    <item>253,DJ</item>
    <item>670,TL</item>
    <item>593,EC</item>
    <item>20,EG</item>
    <item>503,SV</item>
    <item>240,GQ</item>
    <item>291,ER</item>
    <item>372,EE</item>
    <item>251,ET</item>
    <item>500,FK</item>
    <item>298,FO</item>
    <item>679,FJ</item>
    <item>358,FI</item>
    <item>33,FR</item>
    <item>689,PF</item>
    <item>241,GA</item>
    <item>220,GM</item>
    <item>995,GE</item>
    <item>49,DE</item>
    <item>233,GH</item>
    <item>350,GI</item>
    <item>30,GR</item>
    <item>299,GL</item>
    <item>502,GT</item>
    <item>224,GN</item>
    <item>245,GW</item>
    <item>592,GY</item>
    <item>509,HT</item>
    <item>504,HN</item>
    <item>852,HK</item>
    <item>36,HU</item>
    <item>91,IN</item>
    <item>62,ID</item>
    <item>98,IR</item>
    <item>964,IQ</item>
    <item>353,IE</item>
    <item>44,IM</item>
    <item>972,IL</item>
    <item>39,IT</item>
    <item>225,CI</item>
    <item>81,JP</item>
    <item>962,JO</item>
    <item>7,KZ</item>
    <item>254,KE</item>
    <item>686,KI</item>
    <item>965,KW</item>
    <item>996,KG</item>
    <item>856,LA</item>
    <item>371,LV</item>
    <item>961,LB</item>
    <item>266,LS</item>
    <item>231,LR</item>
    <item>218,LY</item>
    <item>423,LI</item>
    <item>370,LT</item>
    <item>352,LU</item>
    <item>853,MO</item>
    <item>389,MK</item>
    <item>261,MG</item>
    <item>265,MW</item>
    <item>60,MY</item>
    <item>960,MV</item>
    <item>223,ML</item>
    <item>356,MT</item>
    <item>692,MH</item>
    <item>222,MR</item>
    <item>230,MU</item>
    <item>262,YT</item>
    <item>52,MX</item>
    <item>691,FM</item>
    <item>373,MD</item>
    <item>377,MC</item>
    <item>976,MN</item>
    <item>382,ME</item>
    <item>212,MA</item>
    <item>258,MZ</item>
    <item>264,NA</item>
    <item>674,NR</item>
    <item>977,NP</item>
    <item>31,NL</item>
    <item>599,AN</item>
    <item>687,NC</item>
    <item>64,NZ</item>
    <item>505,NI</item>
    <item>227,NE</item>
    <item>234,NG</item>
    <item>683,NU</item>
    <item>850,KP</item>
    <item>47,NO</item>
    <item>968,OM</item>
    <item>92,PK</item>
    <item>680,PW</item>
    <item>507,PA</item>
    <item>675,PG</item>
    <item>595,PY</item>
    <item>51,PE</item>
    <item>63,PH</item>
    <item>870,PN</item>
    <item>48,PL</item>
    <item>351,PT</item>
    <item>1,PR</item>
    <item>974,QA</item>
    <item>40,RO</item>
    <item>7,RU</item>
    <item>250,RW</item>
    <item>590,BL</item>
    <item>685,WS</item>
    <item>378,SM</item>
    <item>239,ST</item>
    <item>966,SA</item>
    <item>221,SN</item>
    <item>381,RS</item>
    <item>248,SC</item>
    <item>232,SL</item>
    <item>65,SG</item>
    <item>421,SK</item>
    <item>386,SI</item>
    <item>677,SB</item>
    <item>252,SO</item>
    <item>27,ZA</item>
    <item>82,KR</item>
    <item>34,ES</item>
    <item>94,LK</item>
    <item>290,SH</item>
    <item>508,PM</item>
    <item>249,SD</item>
    <item>597,SR</item>
    <item>268,SZ</item>
    <item>46,SE</item>
    <item>41,CH</item>
    <item>963,SY</item>
    <item>886,TW</item>
    <item>992,TJ</item>
    <item>255,TZ</item>
    <item>66,TH</item>
    <item>228,TG</item>
    <item>690,TK</item>
    <item>676,TO</item>
    <item>216,TN</item>
    <item>90,TR</item>
    <item>993,TM</item>
    <item>688,TV</item>
    <item>971,AE</item>
    <item>256,UG</item>
    <item>44,GB</item>
    <item>380,UA</item>
    <item>598,UY</item>
    <item>1,US</item>
    <item>998,UZ</item>
    <item>678,VU</item>
    <item>39,VA</item>
    <item>58,VE</item>
    <item>84,VN</item>
    <item>681,WF</item>
    <item>967,YE</item>
    <item>260,ZM</item>
    <item>263,ZW</item>
</string-array>
```

But it doesn't contain the whole names, only the short forms. It would be great if there would be a list with the whole names in English.

Additionally I want to give the list another format for displaying, but how do I do that? I use this method from the android doc atm:

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But I don't see how I could edit the item list's content there.

Could you help me?

Comment: WHat do you mean by `I want to give the list another format for displaying` ? what other format you want?

Comment: The way I do it now, my spinner displays the data just like it is written in the item, so '49,DE' for example. But I want to make it like 'Germany (+49)' or something like this

Comment: http://www.mapsofworld.com/world-maps/country-dialing-code.html has a list of country with codes. Take data from there and insert it in your String array.

Answer (score 23):

I have a cleaner solution for you. You can use [Country Code Picker (CCP)](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject) library directly.It will save you from boilerplate code. You just need to place the CountryCodePicker view in your layout XML. This is CCP view [image].

Your view will look like with your phone editText.

[image]

[Download Sample application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.hbb20.countrycodepickerproject) from PlayStore.

Clicking on CCP will open a dialog with a list of country to select from. Here you can search country with country name, code name, phone code. It also gives an option to autoformat phone number.

[image]

Selected country details can be read easily. For more details go to [Library's Github page](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject).

Comment: How to make `Spinner` underlined as `EditText` and both are same level, considering `EditText` inside a `TextInputLayout` ?

Comment: @blueware, can you please elaborate the question?

Comment: @HBB20, check my question here please: [TextInputLayout Alighment Issue with Spinner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764346/textinputlayout-error-alignment-issue-with-appcompat-spinner)

Comment: @blueware, I posted answer there. Let me know if it worked for you. (On that thread only)

Comment: Oh.. what dependencies? If you can create a GitHub issue with details then it will be very helpful. Here is the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject).

Comment: @HBB20 is there anyway I can limit the countries in the list?

Comment: @FatimaHaidar, yes. There are two ways to do it.
1. Add selected countries (https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject/wiki/Custom-Master-Country-List)

                      2. Exclude unwanted countries (https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject/wiki/Exclude-specific-countries)

Answer (score 9):

in gradle :

```
    // country picker
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:1.7.1'
```

in XML

```
<com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
                        android:id="@+id/ccp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/colorGreyF5"
                        android:onClick="onCountryPickerClick"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_10" />
```

in Activity :

```
CountryCodePicker ccp;
ccp = findViewById(R.id.ccp);
    public void onCountryPickerClick(View view) {
        ccp.setOnCountryChangeListener(new CountryCodePicker.OnCountryChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCountrySelected() {
                //Alert.showMessage(RegistrationActivity.this, ccp.getSelectedCountryCodeWithPlus());
                selected_country_code = ccp.getSelectedCountryCodeWithPlus();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I am not getting default selected country code when activity created , only get when i click on the country select spinner even the deafult country is already selected . Any Solution .

Comment: @xaif you should add this attribute
app:ccp_autoDetectCountry="true"

Comment: @SaraTalaat Thanks for your comment. BTW, I already did it :)   For more info try this : https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject

Answer (score 0):

These are [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2). You can find a complete list [on the ISO's website](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_names_and_code_elements).

Running the following code in the JavaScript console (tested using Chrome) gives you a map from codes to countries in JSON format:

```
var result = {}
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var i=1; i<rows.length; i++) {
  var code = rows[i].cells[0].textContent;
  var country = rows[i].cells[1].textContent;
  result[code] = country;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: I know these codes, but I actually don't want to write a translator manually for about 200 countries. Do you know a way I can pull out the data from there?

Comment: you can get these Codes in [CSV File](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/codes/iso3166/) and read it from CSV file

Comment: Ok, I was able to create a string-array as i wanted it in my string.xml - Thanks. But there is still the second issue: How can I change the display format? I already made the array adapter getting his data from a string array from my class instead of the one from the xml file, but how can i import the data to it?

Comment: Alright, I got it by myself after a while. `String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countryCodes);` made it. Now I have an array in my class I can edit.

Comment: Plus one for this answer. Being a programmer contains something else than only using everything ready. It's easy enough for Android dev to run the script. Thanks.