# TextInputLayout error alignment issue with AppCompat Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-appcompat, android-textinputlayout

I am using an app which displays a drop down `Spinner` with an `EditText` as a child of `TextInputLayout` next to it.

When an underlined error is shown under the `TextInputLayout`, then the `EditText` will go up, and alignment will miss !!

See my screenshot please:

[image]

What I am trying to do is:

[image]

Here is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="@dimen/edittext_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_countries"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_mobile"
        style="@style/TextInputLayoutTheme"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="70">

        <com.cashu.app.ui.widgets.CustomEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_fragment_register_step_one_mobile"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/edittext_mobile_num_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="12"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:hint="@string/mobile_hint"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my `TextInputLayout` theme:

```
<!-- TextInputLayout Style -->
<style name="TextInputLayoutTheme" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorControlActivated</item>
    <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.TextErrorAppearance</item>
    <item name="counterTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Counter</item>
    <item name="counterOverflowTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Counter.Overflow</item>
</style>
```

I tried searching for many keywords, terms and methods but unfortunately with no luck.

I would appreciate if anyone has a hack for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem, I set margin to my `AppCompatSpinner` and set top gravity to it with specific hight.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_countries"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_mobile"
            style="@style/TextInputLayoutTheme"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <com.cashu.app.ui.widgets.CustomEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_mobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:ems="12"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="@string/mobile_hint"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**[EDIT]**

When my `TextInputLayout` has an error, I remove it by adding the following lines:

```
myTextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
myTextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
myTextInputLayout.setError(" ");
```

Why?

- This line: `myTextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);` will clear the error from the `TextInputLayout`
- This line: `myTextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);` will enable error for the `TextInputLayout` again
- This line: `myTextInputLayout.setError(" ");` will prevent layout alignment disruption.

Problem now is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Add `app:errorEnabled="true"` in TextInputLayout.

This will leave space for error even if error is not displayed. This will consume more space but will help you to maintain alignment.

Make your TextInputLayout as below.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_mobile"
    style="@style/TextInputLayoutTheme"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="70"
    app:errorEnabled="true">
```

Later in java:

1. To set error text use

   ```
   textInputLayout.setError("Email can not be blank");
   ```
2. To remove error text and set view as normal

   ```
   textInputLayout.setError("");
   ```

*Note that the use of `textInputLayout.setErrorEnable(false)` to remove the error will take out entire text view of error from the textInputLayout which will disturb your alignment.

Comment: At first look, things seems ok, but when an error shows then you type something inside the `EditText` then navigate away from it, the `TextInputLayout` goes bottom as same as the error space !

Comment: How do you disable error? Are you using setErrorEnabled(false); ?

Comment: There is the problem. That will disturb layout alignment. Instead of ```setErrorEnable(false);``` you should use ```setError("");``` to remove error text.

Comment: I am usingt this method `myTextInputLayout.setError("");`

Comment: Earlier you mentioned (in deleted comment) that you were using ```setErrorEnabled(false);``` to remove error text. Anyways ```myTextInputLayout.setError("");``` isn't solving your problem?  It solved the same issue for me.

Comment: This still not solved my problem, the underline color of the `TextInputLayout` still in red. Also layout miss alignment in different locales :(

Comment: I solved my question, please check my answer again, thank you

Answer (score 0):

**try this,**

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_countries"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_mobile"
        style="@style/TextInputLayoutTheme"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="70">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_fragment_register_step_one_mobile"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="12"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:hint="Mobile No."
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: When `TextInputLayout` has an error, the layout misses. The `TextInputLayout` goes up and spinner stays down, any fix for this?