# Where to find the List of getCountryCode() method?

Tags: android

I'm looking for the countryCode list of the Address.class, but I don't know how to find it.

The description in the [Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address#getCountryCode()) is not very usefull, because there is no word about the ISO or a complete list...

## The countries I need the code:

Austria,
Albania,
Andorra,
Armenia,
Azerbaijan,
Belgium,
Bulgaria,
Bosnia and Herzegovina,
Belarus,
Switzerland,
Cyprus,
Czech Republic,
Germany,
Denmark,
Spain,
Estonia,
France,
Finland,
Liechtenstein,
Faeroe Islands,
United Kingdom,
Georgia,
Greece,
Hungary,
Croatia,
Italy,
Ireland,
Iceland,
Kazakhstan,
Luxembourg,
Lithuania,
Latvia,
Malta,
Monaco,
Republic of Moldova,
Macedonia,
Montenegro
Norway,
The Netherlands,
Portugal,
Poland,
Romania,
San Marino,
Russian,
Sweden,
Slovakia,
Serbia,
Slovenia,
Tajikistan,
Turkmenistan,
Turkey,
Ukraine,
Uzbekistan,
Vatican City,
European Community,

Comment: Do you need all country code in a single list

Comment: I will edit from which countries I need.

Comment: Is this link useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421313/creating-a-spinner-for-choosing-country-code

Comment: It is "usefull", but i need the names also, because I don't know every country...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: well i realized at first i answered for languages not for country code. for country code iso 3166 codes are used. it is also mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale). you can use the codes from this [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes) i think.

first answer for languages: iso 639 codes are used for languages in android as mentioned in [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale). so i believe you can use the codes from this [list](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php).

Answer (score 0):

This is my List, I hope someone could need it sometime:

"AT"     Austria,
"AL"     Albania,
"AD"     Andorra,
"AM"     Armenia,
"AZ"     Azerbaijan,
"BE"     Belgium,
"BG"     Bulgaria,
"BA"     Bosnia and Herzegovina,
"BY"     Belarus,
"CH"     Switzerland,
"CY"     Cyprus,
"CZ"     Czech Republic,
"DE"     Germany,
"DK"     Denmark,
"ES"     Spain,
"EE"     Estonia,
"FR"     France,
"FI"     Finland,
"LI"     Liechtenstein,
"FO"     Faeroe Islands,
"GB"     United Kingdom,
"GE"     Georgia,
"GR"     Greece,
"HU"     Hungary,
"HR"     Croatia,
"IT"     Italy,
"IE"     Ireland,
"IS"     Iceland,
"KZ"     Kazakhstan,
"LU"     Luxembourg,
"LT"     Lithuania,
"LV"     Latvia,
"MT"     Malta,
"MC"     Monaco,
"MD"     Republic of Moldova,
"MK"     Macedonia,
"ME"     Montenegro
"NO"     Norway,
"NL"     The Netherlands,
"PT"     Portugal,
"PL"     Poland,
"RO"     Romania,
"SM"     San Marino,
"RU"     Russian,
"SE"     Sweden,
"SK"     Slovakia,
"RS"     Serbia,
"SI"     Slovenia,
"TJ"     Tajikistan,
"TM"     Turkmenistan,
"TR"     Turkey,
"UA"     Ukraine,
"UZ"     Uzbekistan,
"VA"     Vatican City,

By the way, I think it is the 2 Digit ISO android is using in this function.